# Compare two files and store differences using conditional

Tags: linux, awk, compare

I managed to find half of the solution to my challenge, but I cannot find a way to add a conditional to deal with the other half. I am using `awk`. The field separator is `;` and the values are inside double-quotes `"`. The files have only 3x fields each.

I have two files (file1.txt file2.txt) and want to store the differences in a third file(results.txt).

file1.txt

```
"SWITCH1";"rack7";"Datacenter1"
"SWTICH46";"rack1";"rack1"
"ROUTER3";"";"rack1"
"SWITCH7";"rack1";"rack1"
"ROUTER9";"rack1";"rack1"
"ROUTER22";"rack1";"Datacenter4"
```

file2.txt

```
"SWITCH1";"rack7";"Datacenter1"
"ROUTER22";";"Datacenter4"
"SWITCH51";"rack7";"Datacenter2"
```

If I use:

```
awk -F';' 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' file1.txt file2.txt
```

I get:

```
"ROUTER22";";"Datacenter4"
"SWITCH51";"rack7";"Datacenter2"
```

But I want to treat $2 in file2.txt `"` and $2 in file1.txt `rack1` not as a difference between files. Therefore whenever I find an entry on file2.txt that has `"` in field `$2` and `rack1` in field `$2` in file1.txt for the same $1, I do not want to treat as difference and discard it.

The file is generated dynamically nightly and when it happens; field `$2==rack1` in `file1.txt` while field `$2=="` in `file2.txt`. This is the match to exclude as well as the one I managed to exclude with the `awk` command above. Below is the expected output:

Desired results.txt

```
"SWITCH51";"rack7";"Datacenter2"
```

I am struggling to find a conditional to handle this scenario.

Comment: Do you have only 3 fields? And the only condition to exclude a difference is when the difference is exactly that `$2==rack1` in `file1.txt` while `$2=="` in `file2.txt`, but `$1` and `$3` are the same? Please answer by editing your question, not in comments.

Comment: It is still not 100% clear if `rack1` means **exactly** `rack1` (not `rack2`, `rack3`...)  or if it is just an example and could be anything else as long as a single `"` is found in `file2.txt`. Please clarify.

Comment: And you added other ambiguities with "_Therefore whenever I find an entry on `file2.txt` that has `"` in field `$2` and `rack1` in field `$2` in `file1.txt` for the same `$1`, I do not want to treat as difference and discard it._" 1) is it `rack1` or `"rack1"`? 2) What about `$3`? Do you consider that `"foo";"rack1";"bar"` is the same as `"foo";";"qux"` or should the `$3` fields be also equal?

Comment: You should fix the tool that's generating a broken CSV like this that has one double quote in a field of it's own. Can your quoted fields ever contain `;`s? If the answer is yes then your problem is unsolvable, if the answer is no then I wonder why you're quoting the fields in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the original lines in array `a`, like you do, plus modified lines where `"rack1"` is replaced by `"`:

```
$ awk -F';' -vOFS=';' 'FNR==NR {a[$0]; if($2=="\"rack1\"") {$2="\"";a[$0]}; next}
    !($0 in a)' file1.txt file2.txt
"SWITCH51";"rack7";"Datacenter2"
```

Note the specification of the `OFS` output field separator. It is needed because when we modify the `$2` field `awk` reconstructs `$0` using the `OFS` which by default is a space while we need it to remain a semi-column for correct comparison when parsing `file2.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the value of field 2 is just `"` and replace it with `"rack1"`

If after the replacement `$0` is not in array `a` then print the unmodified row which is the `tmp` variable in the example.

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
FNR==NR {a[$0];next} 
{
  tmp = $0
  sub(/^"$/, "\"rack1\"", $2)
  if (!($0 in a)) print tmp
}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Output

```
"SWITCH51";"rack7";"Datacenter2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, in first Input_file's reading creating 2 arrays `a` and `b` with index of $0 and $1,$3 respectively. In next Input_file's reading checking 2 conditions if $1,$3 is NOT present in b AND $0 is not present in a then print that line from Input_file2.

```
awk -F';' '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  b[$1,$3]
  next
}
!(($1,$3) in b) && !($0 in a)
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F';' '
    NR==FNR { a[$0]; next }
    { key = $1 FS ($2 == "\"" ? "\"rack1\"" : $2) FS $3 }
    !(key in a)
' file1.txt file2.txt
"SWITCH51";"rack7";"Datacenter2"
```